# Ruby concurrent tweak for passenger in standalone mode

Tags: websocket, ruby-on-rails-5, passenger

I have a Rails 5.2.3 application with nginx as a reverse proxy and standalone passenger. I am experiencing performance issues with websockets and see that we need to tune passenger when using web sockets as indicated here https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process

I see that when working with nginx we need to make the below changes for specific endpoints to accept unlimited concurrent connections

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name www.example.com;
   root /webapps/my_app/public;
   passenger_enabled on;

   # Use default concurrency for the app. But for the endpoint
   # /special_websocket_endpoint, force a different concurrency.
   location /special_websocket_endpoint {
       passenger_app_group_name foo_websocket;
       passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process 0;
   }
}
```

How can i specify such a configuration when using standalone passenger. Any help on this would be really helpfull. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After checking the documentation found that we can put in configuration details in file named `Passengerconfig.json` on the root of our project.

and concurrent tweak i wanted can be achieved by placing this in the config file

```
{
  "environment": "production",
  "unlimited_concurrency_paths": [
    "/cable"
  ]
}
```

more about configuration variables in standalone mode can be found here

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/docs/references/config_reference/standalone/#--disable-anonymous-telemetry-disable_anonymous_telemetry